# nginx config for nuxt on centos7

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js

I have vps with centos7 operating system. I want to set up a site with nuxt on the server. I'm having trouble configuring nginx. I used the following code in the etc / nginx / nginx.conf file to configure nginx, but I get a 502 error

```
    server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name mydomain.com;

        
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Also I can not access nuxt with my_ip: 5000.

I changed the port from 3000 to 5000.

My site is universal

I run the program with the following code:

"pm2 start npm -- start"

project folder : '/usr/share/nginx/html/myProjectFolder'

Comment: hey, have you looked at this https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy/

Comment: Hello. Yes, it gives the same error again

Comment: are you able to run the project locally?

Comment: Yes. I can even see the index page info with the ```curl -v http://localhost:5000``` command and I think the nginx configuration is causing this error